# Display products of some sub-categories when browsing magento catalog

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have several layers of categories such as:

```
Laundry
    Washers
    Dryers
    Laundry Accessories
```

And I would like users to browse Laundry and see all Washers and Dryers, but not any accessories.  But still allow users to browse through the accessories category by itself, and to use the Layered Navigation while doing so.

Does anyone know a way I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Washers and Dryers categories to be anchors their products will show up in the parent category. This is on the second tab when editing the category.

However, I have found in the 1.4 family (haven't tested 1.5) that changing from not anchored to anchored wouldn't have any affect. This is probably related to a cache I wasn't clearing but the simple solution for me was to delete 'Washers' and create it again, this time making sure Anchor was "yes"

Comment: That doesn't seem to do I'm looking for.  Accessories still appear in the product listings when browsing the Laundry category, but now I can't use Layered Navigation when browsing the Accessory category.

Comment: If you look here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/layered-navigation You will see that to use Layered Navigation the category needs to be an anchor. You may be out of luck here.